# Testing a db migration in rails 7

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-7

I've been trying to write a spec to test a rails migration, but any guides i find online, (e.g. https://nebulab.com/blog/testing-ruby-on-rails-migrations) use the deprecated:
`ActiveRecord::Migrator.new(:up, migrations, current_version).migrate`

what is the equivalent in rails 7?

and has anyone a super simple example of testing a migration in rails 7?

Update:
I have a migration which renames a table and the related rails model, removes a column from that table, adds another column, and finally  migrates existing entries in that table (new column is populated by looking up info using the column that gets dropped)

I mainly want to test that the existing data gets migrated properly

Comment: What are you trying to test EXACTLY? Are you trying to ensure that the tables and columns were actually added to the database? The Rails team has already done that. You shouldn't need to. Or, are you testing that you added the correct tables and columns in the context of your application? Seems like code review or pairing should suffice there, no?

Comment: Several thoughts. 1) that's too much to put in a single migration, 2) you should separate the DB migrations (renaming tables, adding columns) from the data migrations, 3) testing the DB migrations is superfluous - just use code review to ensure correctness, 4) testing the data migration makes sense, but you should be able to do that without needing to actually execute the migration. You should be able to do that by testing that you're sending the right messages to the right objects with the right parameters.